# Hazelcast management center shows get latency of 0 ms for replicated map

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

**Setup** :

- 3 member embedded cluster deployed as a spring boot jar.
- Total keys on each member: 900K
- Get operation is being attempted via a rest api.

**Background**:

- I am trying to benchmark the replicated map of hazelcast.
- Management center UI shows around 10k/s request being executed but avg get latency per sec is coming 0ms.
- I believe it is not showing because it might be in microseconds.

Please let me know how to configure management center UI to show latency in micro/nanoseconds?

Comment: Could you please share which version of Hazelcast and Management Center are you using? In question tags, you have `hazelcast-imap`. Asking just to confirm, are you using replicated map or IMap, as the two are different in Hazelcast?

Comment: @emre tag is just to reach the audience. I am using a replicated map.
**Management center version** - `4.2020.12` **Hazelcast version** - `4.0.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Management center UI shows around 10k/s request being executed but avg get latency per sec is coming 0ms.

I believe you're talking about `Replicated Map Throughput Statistics` in the replicated map details page. The `Avg Get Latency` column in that table shows on average how much time it took for a cluster member to execute the get operations for the time period that is selected on the top right corner of the table. For example, if you select `Last Minute` there, you only see the average time it took for the get operations in the last minute.

> I believe it is not showing because it might be in microseconds.

Cluster is sending it as milliseconds (calculating it as nanoseconds in a newer cluster version but still sending as milliseconds). However, since a replicated map replicates all data on all members and every member contains the whole data set, get latency is typically very low as there's no network trip.

I guess that the way we render very small metric values confused you. In Management Center UI, we only show two fractional digits. You can see it in action in the below screenshots:

[image: The request]

[image: The response]

[image: How it looks like in the Management Center UI]

As you can see, since the value is very low, it is shown as `0`. I believe we can do a better job rendering these values though (using a smaller time unit for example). I will create an issue for this on our private issue tracker.

Comment: Hi, yes that would be helpful to understand and publish benchmarks to our peers/leaders in orgs while we try to evaluate hazelcast vs redis.
Yes, what I tried was for replicated map only. As with distributed map I was able to see >0ms latency.